# R: select from nested list by ID

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list where the first term contains the ID and the other terms contains characteristics associated with that ID:

```
list3  = list(list("a","b","c","d","e","f"), list(1:6), list(c(10,20,30,40,50,60))
list3
```

I would like to then select from this list by ID to just get the terms associated with that ID :
I tried:

```
ID="e"
listselect <- list3[list3[[1]]==ID]
listselect
```

But this does not work.
I was hoping to get just the terms associated with e:
listselect: e, 5,50

I would be grateful for your help.

Comment: How is 50 associated with "e"?

Comment: `10:60` gives vector with 51 numbers... How do you relate these to IDs?

Comment: I apologise. I made a mistake. I have now corrected the third term.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can proceed with:

```
x = 'e'

lapply(list3[-1], function(u) u[[1]][which(list3[[1]]==x)])

#[[1]]
#[1] 5

#[[2]]
#[1] 50
```

Or even neater:

```
rapply(list3[-1], `[[`, ...=which(list3[[1]]==x), how="unlist")
```

Comment: I added the correct solution to go through list of lists with rapply.

Answer (score 4):

Colonel Beauvel's answer is good, but I'll add: this is a case where you really want a data.frame and not a list of lists.

```
# the data
list3  = list(list("a","b","c","d","e","f"), list(1:6), list(seq(10,60,10)))

# convert to data.frame and fix names
df3 <- data.frame(lapply(list3, unlist))
names(df3) <- paste0('v', 1:ncol(df3))

# now you can do this - so easy!
df3[df3[, 1] == 'e', ]
```

Result:

```
  v1 v2 v3
5  e  5 50
```

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, the OP should be using a data.frame. Nice use of `lapply()` and `unlist()` to build the data.frame; I was heading down a more complex path involving `do.call()`. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want this:

```
 list3  = list(list("a","b","c","d","e","f"), 1:6, 10*(1:6))
```

Then you can get these:

```
 lidx <- list3[[1]]=="e"
 list3[[2]][lidx] 
 # [1] 5
 list3[[3]][lidx]
 # [1] 50
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to index the list appropriately to get what you want. Your command `listselect <- list3[list3[[1]]==ID]` returns `FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE` which is the same as returning "5", so when you index `list3[5]` you get the fifth list in the nested list, which doesn't exist in your case. If you want to get the part of each list associated with e, you'd have to either index them separately as in `c(list3[[2]][list3[[1]]==ID], list3[[3]][list3[[1]]==ID])` or loop through the length of `list3` as in `list3[[i]][list3[[1]]==ID]` and save those to listselect as you go.